# script.jip : bad interpreter

Tags: python, bash, interpreter

I tried to launch a script like this :

> jitterbug.jip

But when I try, I have this error :

> -bash: jip_scripts/jitterbug.jip: /software/so/el6.3/PythonPackages-2.7.6/bin/jip: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

The head of the script :

**

```
> #!/software/so/el6.3/PythonPackages-2.7.3-VirtualEnv/bin/python
> #####!/software/so/el6.3/PythonPackagesVirtualEnv/bin/python
> 
> #path for loki etc: #!/soft/bin/python
> # elizabeth henaff
> # Feb 2012
> # elizabeth.henaff@cragenomica.es
> 
> 
> import getopt,sys
> -bash-4.1$ head jip_scripts/jitterbug.jip 
> #!/software/so/el6.3/PythonPackages-2.7.6/bin/jip
> #
> #
> # Run jitterbug on the specified bam file and annotation
```

**

I don't know if it could help but some informations :

- I work on a cluster but I have to install tools in my home directory.
- In the README they said :

> first of all, to use jip you need to export the following environment variable:
>
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/software/so/el6.3/PythonPackages-2.7.6/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

I did it, but I am not sure to really understand the "export" thing. I am not sure if I just have to copy/paste or if I have to change something. If you can explain to me the notion of the PATH too, I will appreciate.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Does `ls -l /software/so/el6.3/PythonPackages-2.7.6/bin/jip` show that this file *does* in fact exist?

Comment: No! In fact, I don't find the /software directory :o

Comment: Well, that's the problem -- the line `#!/software/so/el6.3/PythonPackages-2.7.6/bin/jip` means "use the program at `/software/so/el6.3/PythonPackages-2.7.6/bin/jip` to run this script". Whoever built the script you're using, then, *intended* it to be run on a very specific system with a `/software` directory.

Comment: ...if you have a Python installation you want to use elsewhere (for instance, an activated [`virtualenv`](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) in your home directory with `jip` and whatever other dependencies are needed installed), consider changing the shebangs to `#!/usr/bin/env python` and `#!/usr/bin/env jip`, to honor your system's `PATH` (which `virtualenv` can update) to find those tools.

Comment: So, just to be sure I understand :

1) I have to activate a virtualenv in my home directory 
2) I install on it jip
3) I change the shebangs

Right ?

Comment: Yup. There might be other dependencies needed as well, but that'll at least get you started.

Comment: Mmmh sorry but I realized that the head of my file is :

`#!/software/so/el6.3/PythonPackages-2.7.6/bin/jip

# Run jitterbug on the specified bam file and annotation`

So I install as you said jip on a virtualenv (I used pyenv)

And so, now, what I have to write after the #! ? The path of the jip ?
Really sorry for the head file!

Comment: If you've *activated* the virtualenv, then `#!/usr/bin/env jip` (which means "use the `jip` binary from your `PATH`") should work.

Comment: I am really sorry and thank you so much for your help but when I try to launch the script, now I have this error :

<pre>local/jitterbug-code/jip_scripts/jitterbug.jip   
usage: jip [-h]
           {clean,remove,freeze,install,deps,update,resolve,version,search,list}
           ...
jip: error: argument command: invalid choice: 'local/jitterbug-code/jip_scripts/jitterbug.jip' (choose from 'clean', 'remove', 'freeze', 'install', 'deps', 'update', 'resolve', 'version', 'search', 'list')</pre>

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if it's a different command under the `jip` name -- a package manager isn't a likely candidate to be used as an interpreter, indeed. Unfortunately, if you need to find and install a different program also named jip, I'm not likely to be much help in identifying it.